# Dividing Fractions in differential equations

Tags: fractions

I know this has been asked in many forms. But still confused.
I am re-learning differential equations and I was working on Verifying solutions.

Is $g(x) = (\frac{\sqrt 3x^2}{2})$ a solution to $\displaystyle g'(x) = \frac{3x}{4g(x)}$

When plugging in.. I get confused with

$\displaystyle\frac{3x}{4\frac{\sqrt 3x^2}{2}}$

If you have $\frac ab$ ÷ $\frac pq$  you $\frac ab$ x $\frac qp$  ...I know why

But what do you do when $\displaystyle\frac a{b({\frac pq})}$ ...especially for such cases.

Comment: This is not related to differential equations, please edit the tags.

Comment: Per above, then the title is also not relevant.

Comment: Think of $\frac{a/b}{p/q} = \frac{(a/b) \times bq}{(p/q)\times bq} = \frac{aq}{bp}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \dfrac{a}{\frac{bp}{q}} = a \cdot \dfrac{q}{bp} $$

This is because $a ÷ \dfrac{b}{c}=a \cdot \dfrac{c}{b}$. You can get more information [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/fractions_division.html).